# UIButton doesn't works when the user scroll down

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

i'm italian, so sorry for my bad english!

So... i have a UITableView and every cell open a xib file with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
                 detail = [[name_class alloc] initWithNibName:@"name_xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                 detail.navigationItem.title = @"Title";}
  //then the others indexPath.row with the others xib
```

and then

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
[detail release];
detail = nil;
```

Every xib has his .m and .h file.
Every xib has this structure: UIScrollView -> UIView -> UITextView/UIImageView/UIButton

When my UIButton has Y>460 (so the user has to scroll down for see it) the uibuttons "works and doesn't works"!
Some times the uibutton works but only if you touch in some area, not in all the uibutton area!
Other times the uibutton doesn't works, it's impossible touch it (or better, if you touch it nothing happen!)

I'm sure that this happen only when the uibuttons are "down" (have Y>460).
I've tried in the simulator and in the device!

Isn't absurd?? O_O

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should post your scrollview code for more understanding as you have problem in scrollview,i have not seen your code so i am not sure about this but you might forget to increase **contentView size of scrollview** thats y you face your problem.
Just see if you have enough contentView size set and still not working then add your code here for getting better answer from anyone here.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe beacuse i'm a newbie, i have used IB to create the UIScrollView. The ScrollView is large 320x460 and in the "Content" area, the Inset -> Bottom value is the height of the UIView inside the view. So... in this exaple, the UIScrollView has "content -> inset -> bottom" value == 655. The UIView (inside the scrollview) has W:320 H:655... isn't correct?

Comment: OOOK, i've solved! My UIView was too short and the UIButton were inside the uiscrollview (not in the uiview)! The color background was the same, so it was difficoult see the problem!  Thanks :)